# Google Cloud Print Web Element works but not on Google Chrome for iOS

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-cloud-print, chrome-ios

I use GCP Web Element to post items to print on my web application, here's the code Google suggests...

JavaScript

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/cloudprint/client/cpgadget.js">
</script>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var gadget = new cloudprint.Gadget();
gadget.setPrintButton(
        cloudprint.Gadget.createDefaultPrintButton("print_button_container")); //div id to contain the button
gadget.setPrintDocument("url", "Test Page", "http://www.google.com/landing/cloudprint/testpage.pdf");
}
</script>
```

HTML...

```
<div id="print_button_container"></div>
```

This all works fine, it posts the document fine and it prints on... Browser on Android 3.2, Google Chrome for Windows and Safari on iOS

However it doesn't post the document (and therefore doesn't print) on Google Chrome for iOS

Which makes no sense as Google makes Chrome for iOS and also makes cloud print.

Anyone got an idea how to fix this, or do i just have to wait for Google to fix it in Chrome for iOS?